# DataTables draw not functioning

Tags: javascript, datatables

I do not know what I am missing or what is wrong with my code, I already tried tracing it from the console but the `TransmittedDataTable.on('draw'` does not work. What's wrong with my code?

Javascript Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
GetData()
});

function GetData() {
        var TransmittedDataTable = $('#tbtransmitteddata').dataTable({
            autoWidth: true,
            initComplete: function () {
                //this.api().columns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]).every(function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;

                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw(function () {

                        });
                });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            },
            'drawCallback': function (settings) {
                //var api = this.api();
                // Output the data for the visible rows to the browser's console
                //console.log(api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data());
            },
            processing: true,
            ajax: {
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '../Application/ApplicationWS.asmx/GetDepEdTransmittal2',
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                    return JSON.parse(json.d);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "Region" },
                { data: "Division" },
                { data: "Station" },
                { data: "EmployeeNumber" },
                { data: "EmployeeName" },
                { data: "DednCode" },
                { data: "PolicyNo" },
                { data: "EffectDate" },
                { data: "TermDate" },
                { data: "Amount" },
                { data: "LoanAmount" },
                { data: "InterestAmount" },
                { data: "OtherCharges" },
                { data: "BillingType" },
                { data: "UpdateCode" }
            ],
            //deferLoading: 57,
            'columnDefs': [
            { 'targets': 4, 'title': 'Employee Name' },
            { 'targets': 5, 'title': 'Deduction Code' },
            { 'targets': 7, 'title': 'Effectivity Date' },
            { 'targets': 8, 'title': 'Termination Date' },
            { 'targets': 9, 'title': 'Deduction Amount' },
            { 'targets': 10, 'title': 'Loan Amount' },
            { 'targets': 11, 'title': 'Interest Amount' },
            { 'targets': 12, 'title': 'Other Charges' },
            { 'targets': 13, 'title': 'Billing Type' },
            { 'targets': 14, 'title': 'Update Code' }
            //{ "targets": [13], "visible": false, "searchable": false }
            ]
            //,scrollY:'50vh',
            , dom: 'Blfrtip'
            , colReorder: true
            , buttons: [{
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                download: 'open',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                title: 'BILLING LIST & PROMISORRY NOTES',
                //message: 'BILLING LIST & PROMISORRY NOTES',
                exportOptions: {
                    //columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                },
                customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.content.splice(0, 0, {
                        margin: [0, 0, 0, 10],
                        alignment: 'center',
                        image: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
                    });

                    //console.log(doc.content[2]);

                    //doc.content[2].table.widths = [40, 40, 40, 60, 100, 40];
                }
            }]
        });
         TransmittedDataTable.on('draw.dt', function () {
            TransmittedDataTable.columns().indexes().each(function (idx) {
                var select = $(TransmittedDataTable.column(idx).footer()).find('select');

                if (select.val() === '') {
                    select
                      .empty()
                      .append('<option value=""/>');

                    TransmittedDataTable.column(idx, { search: 'applied' }).data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

}

I already updated my code, tried `draw.dt` but a new error came out, in browers console an error shows `Uncaught TypeError: TransmittedDataTable.columns is not a function(…)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like you need to use drawCallback.  I notice you have tried something, but it's now commented out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `.dt` to event name if you've used jQuery object or initialized your table with `dataTable()`, see example below.

```
TransmittedDataTable.on('draw.dt', function(){

});
```

If you initialized your table with `DataTable()`, `.dt` suffix is not needed.

Since you're trying to access other API methods using `TransmittedDataTable` variable, initialize your table with `DataTable()` and everything would work as expected.

See [Events](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) for more information.

Comment: i tried your code and it already trigger the event but now i am having another problem,'Uncaught TypeError: TransmittedDataTable.columns is not a function(…)'

Comment: @Angelo11292, initialize your table with `DataTable()` instead of `dataTable()` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on the site about the `.dt` suffix, but adding it caused the event to fire as expected. Thanks!